# How do I stop visual studio inserting a space into JavaScript code on build/rebuild?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2019

I am using Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise. When I build/rebuild my solution ASP.net 4 MVC my JavaScript files are removed as they are regenerated by my TypeScript files.

However the new JavaScript files have a single trailing space after `{ or } or ;`

I have tried to remove the Autoformatting for JS/TS in tools => options but still those single trailing space are added.

Any idea?

So Far I have tried re-installing VS 2019 and change the tools option settings for JS/TS

This is my TypeScript settings Build:
[image]

Comment: are you using prettier?

Comment: @rnewed_user  - no I am not using prettier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be helpful to anyone else - but I will leave it here just in case someone else will face this weird problem.

I have spent some time on this one, reinstalled VS2019, re pulling repo changing settings on VS.

None of those helped - however I have reinstalled Git with a change

[image]

Now when I rebuild the generated JS files don't have trailing spaces. Hence GitKraken or VS git don't pick any changes.

I though about using this settings because in VS2019 as in the editor window bottom right hand side it clearly set to CRLF.